# Can't send logs with ' syslogd '

Tags: busybox

I configured syslogd to send the traces to the card ( host : 10.1.1.1 )  knowing that the card has syslog-ng.

***goal***

Configure syslog-ng as a server
Configure syslogd as a client

***Steps***

1- Configuring syslog-ng as a server
2- Disable firewall (can ping the server)
3- Start syslogd on busybox with the command "syslogd -R 10.1.1.1:514"

*** Problems***

No packets send with syslogd (test with tcpdump), even if I tested with the command:
-syslogd -R 10.1.1.1:514 -L -O / var / log / messages

Answer (score 0):

Try with this command:

```
busybox syslogd -n -O /var/log/messages -S -s 200 -b 5 -R 10.1.1.1:514 -m 20 &
```

Please check the process is running properly or not, is there any error getting while running the above command. If so modify the 
`/etc/syslog.conf` accordingly since **syslog.conf** is being used by **syslogd** daemon.

Use the syslog server e.g: **syslog watcher** set the IP properly and start the server.